# Unable to Get Application Icons to Display with GTK4 under Ubuntu

Tags: icons, gtk, gnome, gtk4

Recent articles about GTK4 detail the changes required for displaying application icons. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114626/why-gtk4-seems-to-use-only-48x48-icons-for-displaying-minimized-application-in-a) in particular is very helpful in explaining how to deploy desktop files and icons.

I am seeing an issue where the application icons display correctly with GTK3 apps, but the default widget icon displays for GTK4 apps. One thing to mention up front is that I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with the latest updates inside a VirtualBox VM hosted under Windows 10.

To test this behavior, I have created a file called HelloWorld.c that contains the following code, which is derived from The GTK Project's [Getting Started](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world) page and compiles successfully under both GTK3 and GTK4:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

The file resides in a folder called "$HOME/Projects/HelloWorld3,4" and is compiled to produce executables named HelloWorld3 and HelloWorld4 as follows:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld3 `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld4 `pkg-config --libs gtk4`
```

HelloWorld3.desktop is as follows. To simplify matters for this example, I am not installing any custom icons. There is already an icon called "preferences-color.png" under /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*(icon size)*/apps. Of course, "*(my home folder)*" is simply a placeholder for this example; the actual file on my system contains the correct full path to the executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Hello World GTK 3
Exec=/(my home folder)/Projects/HelloWorld3,4/HelloWorld3
Comment=Hello World with Application-Specific Icon
Icon=preferences-color
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;GTK;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26
```

HelloWorld4.desktop is as follows (again, "*(my home folder)*" is simply a placeholder for this example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Hello World GTK 4
Exec=/(my home folder)/Projects/HelloWorld3,4/HelloWorld4
Comment=Hello World with Application-Specific Icon
Icon=preferences-color
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;GTK;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26
```

According to the article I referenced at the top of this post, the desktop files can either be copied to $HOME/.local/share/applications or installed under /usr/share/applications using [desktop-file-install](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-desktop-file-install/). Both methods have been attempted, with the same results. For sake of completeness, the latter method was used as follows:

```
sudo desktop-file-install --dir=/usr/share/applications ./HelloWorld3.desktop
sudo desktop-file-install --dir=/usr/share/applications ./HelloWorld4.desktop
```

After all is said and done, launching HelloWorld3 shows the preferences-color icon, but launching HelloWorld4 shows the default widget icon. Rebooting has no effect on the outcome.

Hopefully I have provided enough information, but please let me know if you have any questions. Any suggestions on where the issue may lie would be very helpful.